# How to connect an AWUS1900 to a Kali Virtual Box VM hosted on Windows 11?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux

I have done the following:

On the host:
Installed the driver

Inside Kali:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms

On Virtualbox:

Bridge access
USB 2.0 Controller

When I launch lsusb, iwconfig or ifconfig my device is properly identified. However, when I attempt to connect to my Wi-Fi, once I've entered the WPA key, the Network Manager icon in the task bar disapears and I'm left with no connection and no error message. I think the problem is related to Virtual Box but I couldn't find anything on the internet that help me fix it.

Comment: AWUS1900 appears to be a USB wireless adapter.   Make sure you have USB passthrough enabled and a Kali driver for the USB wireless card. It is not a host issue.

Comment: I have USB passthrough enabled and the driver is realtek-rtl88xxau, as I wrote.

Comment: Is the RealTek driver Kali compatible.?

Comment: Yes it is. It worked perfectly well  with Vmware Workstation.

Comment: You may then wish to switch back to VMware.  That is what I use.

Comment: I would if I knew how to scale the display. Display is too small on it and there again I could not find any fix on the internet.

Comment: I have Kali here with VMware Tools installed and Kali Guest size is proper and scrolling works. Was V16 when I posted. Now is VMware V17 and it continues to be good.

Comment: How did you parameter display on it?

Comment: I just installed VMware Tools via in Kali . Newer versions of VMware install Linux tools automatically and that has worked well for me. It used to be more complicated in earlier versions.